# How to center a div exactly at the center(horizontally and verically) of a parent div in IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

The styles are:

```
.innerdiv{
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
width: 300px;
}
.outerdiv{
text-align: center;
background: #c0c0c0;
}
.outerdiv .before,.outerdiv:before {
content: '';
display: inline-block;
/**display: inline;*/
height: 100%;
vertical-align: middle;
margin-right: -0.25em;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div style="height:500px" class="outerdiv">

 <div class="innerdiv">
   <span class="" style="font-size:26px">Hello </span>
   <br/>
   <img style="width:150px" src="http://mrsdalesworkspace.pbworks.com/f/1302032618/desert(1).jpg"/>
 </div>
```

I want to center the inner div both horizontally and vertically with respect to outer div and the above code works fine everywhere except IE7.

I think due to the presence of 'before' pseudo class it is not working in IE7.

I tried fixing it using

styles are:

```
.outerdiv{
text-align: center;
background: #c0c0c0;
*zoom: expression( 
this.runtimeStyle.zoom="1",
this.appendChild( document.createElement("small") ).className="after",
this.insertBefore( document.createElement("small"), this.firstChild ).className="before"
);
```

}

```
.outerdiv .before,.outerdiv:before {
content: '';
display: inline-block;
/**display: inline;*/
height: 100%;
vertical-align: middle;
margin-right: -0.25em;
```

}

I am unable to do it using this one too.

I even tried using the plugin

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
<script src="http://ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn/version/2.1(beta4)/IE8.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

and also

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jquery.lukelutman.com/plugins/pseudo/jquery.pseudo.js"></script>
```

It still did not work.

I know that using `position:absolute` and setting the top and left margins and positions we can achieve it. I want to achieve it using pseudo classes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8779607/center-div-content-fluid-vertical-and-horizontal  follow this

Answer (score 2):

This should work, in every browsers:

```
.outerdiv {
     position:relative;
}

.outerdiv .innerdiv {
     position:absolute;
     top:50%;
     left:50%;
     width:200px;
     height:200px;
     margin-top:-100px; // height / 2
     margin-left:-100px; // width /2 
}
```

Comment: I know that this will work in every browser but I need a solution using pseudo classes please..

Comment: Why do you want to use pseudo classes? You can use http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/ which is a js hack... See stackoverflow.com/questions/4181884/after-and-before-css-pseudo-elements-hack-for-ie-7 for more information

Answer (score 1):

IE7 simply does not understand `::before` and `::after`.

This means it does not understand the `.outerdiv .before,.outerdiv:before` combined selector either. You should separate them.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this class :

```
.center {
     position: absolute; /* do not change */
     top: 50%; /* do not change */
     left: 50%; /* do not change */
     width: 80%; /* 80% of the parent's width. Of course, you can change this value. */
     height: 80%; /* 80% of the parent's width. Of course, you can change this value. */
     margin-top: -40%;  /* current height / 2 */
     margin-left: -40%; /* current width / 2 */
}
```

[Example on codepen.io](http://codepen.io/AloisDeGouvello/pen/CfDvA)